# Display values of json returned by python file in html webpage seperately

Tags: python, html, flask

I am making a webapp for OCR on document with layoutlm using flask, website has upload system that accepts images and documents which are later processed by a python file for OCR which returns a JSON containing 'key' as field name like 'Name', 'DOB' and value as corresponding answer to the field as 'Akshit', '17/02/2002'. I have got the upload system working but am not able to figure out how I display these values into my HTML webpage. Can you please help?

app.py:-

```
from flask import Flask

UPLOAD_FOLDER = r'path\to\upload\folder'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "secret key"
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 16 * 1024 * 1024
```

main.py :-

```
#import magic
import urllib.request

from invoice_docquery import ret_scores
from app import app
from flask import Flask, flash, request, redirect, render_template
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg'])

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS
    
@app.route('/')
def upload_form():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # check if the post request has the file part
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No file selected for uploading')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))

            json_ans = ret_scores(filename)     # Performs OCR and returns json containing key as field names and value as its corresponding answers

            flash('File successfully uploaded')
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            flash('Allowed file types are pdf, png, jpg, jpeg')
            return redirect(request.url)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

HTML code so far (index.html):-

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Python Flask File Upload Example</title>
<h2>Select a file to upload</h2>
<p>
    {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
      {% if messages %}
        <ul class=flashes>
        {% for message in messages %}
          <li>{{ message }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}
</p>
<form method="post" action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <dl>
        <p>
            <input type="file" name="file" autocomplete="off" required>
        </p>
    </dl>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </p>
</form>
```

function 'ret_scores' in main.py returns the required json for which I want to display its values in the HTML webpage

Do let me know if any additional information is required

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to diagnose exactly what your issue is as you didn't explain what output you're getting (error message? no content showing?), but the issue appears to be in the way you're trying to use the jinja template, in particular in the line:

```
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
```

What is get_flashed_messages() and how does the template know where to find it?

You pass information to templates as parameters in `render_template`, so your `@app.route('/')` will need to contain a line like:

```
 return render_template('index.html', messages)
```

Passing variables between routes gets messy and confusing, so I recommend using session variables to store the information that you will pass to the template.

I've rewritten your code to demonstrate the basic flow, but **please don't expect it to run first time** as I haven't run it to test. There may still be some debugging to do but hopefully it should demonstrate the general idea and get you moving in the right direction.

`app.py` looks fine as-is.

`main.py`:

```
#import magic
import urllib.request

from invoice_docquery import ret_scores
from app import app
from flask import Flask, flash, request, redirect, render_template
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg'])

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS
    
@app.route('/')
def upload_form():
    if session['messages']:
        return render_template('index.html', messages=session['messages'])
    else:
        return render_template('index.html', messages={})


@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # check if the post request has the file part
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No file selected for uploading')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            session['messages'] = ret_scores(filename)     # Performs OCR and returns json containing key as field names and value as its corresponding answers
            flash('File successfully uploaded')
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            flash('Allowed file types are pdf, png, jpg, jpeg')
            return redirect(request.url)
            

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

`index.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Python Flask File Upload Example</title>
<h2>Select a file to upload</h2>
<p>
    {% if messages %}
    <ul class=flashes>
        {% for message in messages %}
        <li>{{ message }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% endif %}
</p>
<form method="post" action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <dl>
        <p>
            <input type="file" name="file" autocomplete="off" required>
        </p>
    </dl>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </p>
</form>
```

Feel free to ask any question is in the comments and I'll do my best to help when I can.